# Suggestions on getting Highstocks graph images sent to server

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I know highstocks gives the option to download the chart images via javascript on the client side, but I was wondering if they have released a preferred method of generating these images on hosted server?

Comment: i'm not sure why this isn't a real question. seems valid to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the chart export server on your local machine to do browser-less exporting of charts. See [this](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) link. What you can do using the phantomJS interface is send the chart definition to the export server and it will spit out whatever file format you want (PDF, JPEG, SVG, PNG). You can then use these chart image files in any other fashion - downloadable files, static images on the page, etc.

Comment: Very nice information!

Comment: Perfect! Today, you are my hero!